# Using Postman and Soapui I get a 400 when hitting a Spring Boot endpoint, but Swagger has no problem

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations, postman, soapui

The endpoint is in a RestController with this signature:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/unclaim")
@Operation(summary = "Unclaim Tasks ")
public BaseResponse<String> claimTasks(
        @RequestParam(required = true, name = "taskIds") Long taskIds[]
        ) 
{
```

If I use Soap ui to the correct URL ( I know I got that right, b/c if I append another character to it, I get a 404 ) I send this payload:

```
{
taskIds: [ 444, 34, 55 ]
}
```

Doing this in SoapUI and Postman both give 400s and no explanation :

HTTP/1.1 400
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=C18701F799961FEECF967457574EB914; Path=/tlmapi; HttpOnly
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 02 Sep 2022 16:11:44 GMT
Connection: close

But going to the swagger-ui.html page for this controller lets me construct a request that works :

[image]

[image]

So what's the difference ? Or is there a way to see the payload that swagger is sending?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I accidentally was using the @RequestParam annotation on the list, instead of @RequestBody. Further, the param was Required, so spring rejected it and ignored my Json payload from SoapUI and Postman.

Hope this helps someone not waste a couple of hours...